# Calculate total no . of case per category, given case rate per $100,000$ and total no. of cases

Tags: arithmetic, percentages

I have the information on case rate per category

Eg - $$A \to 97 \text{ per } 100,000$$
$$B \to 169 \text{ per } 100,000$$
$$C \to 189 \text{ per } 100,000$$
$$D \to 234 \text{ per } 100,000$$
$$E \to 241 \text{ per } 100,000$$
$$F \to 420 \text{ per } 100,000$$

The total no. tests is $148,126$ and the total no. of confirmed cases is $10,490$

How should I calculate the total no. of cases per category?

Thank you

Comment: Are the categories mutually exclusive and exhaustive?  That is, does every case belong to exactly one of the six categories?

Comment: You need cathegory weights $w_i$, then you'll have $N\sum\limits_{n=1}^{6} p_iw_i=n=10490$ where $N$ is total population and $p_1=97\cdot 10^{-5},\,\ldots,\,p_6=420\cdot 10^{-5}$ then $Np_iw_i$ will be the desired value.

Comment: Yes, every case belong to exactly one of the six categories

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?page=2&tab=Votes Here is a Mathjax tutorial to help you format math text on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$
97 + 169 + 189 + 234 + 241 + 420=1350$$

So out of $10490$ cases, we expect that $$\frac{97}{1350}\cdot10490 = 753.726$$ cases belong to category A, and so on for the other categories.